# Fetch same digits number

Tags: mysql, sql

MySQL Database:

```
+-----------+
| Number    | {bigint(10)}
+-----------+
| 9599595995|
+-----------+
| 8438084380|
+-----------+
| 8959329599|
+-----------+
| 7778278236|
+-----------+
```

It's easy to fetch same sequence like: *ABCDE-ABCDE*, by using

```
SELECT * FROM numbers WHERE LEFT(Number, 5) = RIGHT(Number, 5)
```

Results:-

> 9599595995 and 8438084380

What will be the query to fetch same 3 digits:- xxabcabcxx or xxabcxxabc or abcxxxabcx or abcabcxxxx or xxxxabcabc

Results:-

> 9599595995, 8438084380, 8959329599 and 7778278236

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Can you try to clarify your question? Which 3 digits, and why?

Comment: 8 **959** 32 **959** 9   and 77 **782** **782** 36  i really don't know why

Comment: `8 *959* 32 *959* 9` and `77 *782* *782* 36`, see @Qirel the number have same series

Comment: @nbk you got it.

Comment: @paran why not 9599595995?

Comment: @paran why not 8438084380? All rows should be fetched.

Comment: @forpas, ohh yes I missed those...

Comment: Updated the question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With UNION ALL construct a series of numbers from 1 to 5, so to get all possible 3 digit substrings of each number:

```
select distinct n.number
from (
  select 1 start union all select 2  union all select 3 union all 
  select 4 union all select 5 
) s cross join numbers n
where n.number like concat(
  '%', substring(n.number, s.start, 3), 
  '%', substring(n.number, s.start, 3), '%'
)
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7BTx3CM4zSrHu3xLHCJRPK/1) (I added more rows).
With:

```
insert into numbers (number) values
('1234567890'),
('1234567123'), 
('4567123123'),                                      
('1231245675'),                                     
('9599595995'),
('8438084380'),
('8959329599'),
('7778278236');
```

Results:

```
| number     |
| ---------- |
| 1234567123 |
| 4567123123 |
| 9599595995 |
| 8438084380 |
| 8959329599 |
| 7778278236 |
```

Comment: Why 1 to 8? Why not 1 to 6 or 1 to 10?

Comment: I edited, it is needed from 1 to 5. The last 3 digit part that needs to be checkes is from position 5 (chars in positions 5, 6 and 7).

Comment: I have 3 more column in the table and I also want to fetch them, but when I fetch it says undefined

Comment: Join this query to the table like this: `select * from numbers t inner join (<the query here>) n on n.number = t.number`

Answer (score 1):

Check first 10 - 3*2  + 1 = 5 positions

```
SELECT * FROM numbers
WHERE POSITION(SUBSTRING(Number,1,3) IN SUBSTRING(Number,4,10)) > 0
    OR POSITION(SUBSTRING(Number,2,3) IN SUBSTRING(Number,5,10)) > 0
    OR POSITION(SUBSTRING(Number,3,3) IN SUBSTRING(Number,6,10)) > 0
    OR POSITION(SUBSTRING(Number,4,3) IN SUBSTRING(Number,7,10)) > 0
    OR SUBSTRING(Number,5,3) = SUBSTRING(Number,8,10)
```

Comment: this is kinda a weird request but this is the best way to do it that i can think of, upvoted. possibly could write a stored procedure to do the same thing...